# Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0)

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, mapping, struct

**Need this architecture**

```
{
      address1 => [struct1, struct2],
      address2 => [struct1, struct2, struct3,],
      address3 => [struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5],
      ...
}
```

**My Attempt**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Owner {

    uint private _ids;

    struct UserDetails {
        uint256 id;
        string title;
    }

    mapping (address => UserDetails[]) public users;
    mapping (address => uint256) public userDetails; 

    function createPost(string memory _title) public {
        _ids ++; 
        uint256 _users = users[msg.sender].push(UserDetails(_ids, _title)); 
        userDetails[msg.sender] = _users;
    }
}
```

but i cant push struct into the mapping, it's showing me error:

***TypeError: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0).***

please help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `uint256 _users =`  in the createPost() so that `uint256 _users = users[msg.sender].push(UserDetails(_ids, _title));`  becomes `users[msg.sender].push(UserDetails(_ids, _title));`

Comment: but i want to save this in a variable. 


`uint256 _users = users[msg.sender].push(UserDetails(_ids, _title)); 
userDetails[msg.sender] = _users;`


i want to achieve this basically

Comment: please have  look on my question again, i edited my code.

Comment: So what I understand is that you are trying to keep number of elements from the struct array in userDetails mapping.
if that is the case then

`function createPost(string memory _title) public {
        _ids ++; 
        users[msg.sender].push(UserDetails(_ids, _title)); 
        userDetails[msg.sender] = users[msg.sender].length;
    }`

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked. Thank u :)

Comment: I am glad. Cheers :)